# An alternative to nested has many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, relationship

I am porting a very old legacy application from PHP to rails and came across some functionality that I am not sure how to implement in a 'proper' RoR way.

Basically we have a signup form that collects leads, one of the attribues on a lead is thier state of residence e.g; Alaska, Florida, etc.

We also have customers who log into a backend and can retrive a list of leads. These customers have their list filtered by state, and their 'allowed' states are associated with their account.

The original PHP application, written long before I came here uses a rather complex method of making a row for every state 'owned' by a customer, meaning there is a row for Arizona for every customer who has Arizona. This states cross reference table has gotten rather large, and it created some nasty nested loops as the PHP code parses customers based on these lookups.

I thought of making rails model called States and making a customer has many states and a state has many leads relationship, but there must be a better way.

Another option is to save the list of states as an array for each customer and then save that array as text in one row and then query the database using the array, or make a row for every state for every customer record and have each state with an on or off status.

I feel like I'm missing a built-in function of rails because this seems like a fairly common type of relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not serialize a list of states for the customers since that will make SQL queries difficult. Your best bet is probably creating a many-to-many relationship between customers and states (the `allowed_states` table would hold a `customer_id` and a `state_id`).

A setup like this might work for you:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :allowed_states
  has_many :states, :through => :allowed_states
end

def State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, :through => :allowed_states
  has_many :leads

end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state

  def self.filter_allowed_for(customer)
    where(:state_id => customer.state_ids)
  end
end
```

This way you can simply retrieve a filtered list of leads for a particular customer. Note that the customer - states relationship creates a `state_ids` method on the customer instance.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association   Ah ha! I knew there was some method or relationship that could make this easier. I didn't want to have to create a whole table just for states but this looks like it will be pretty efficient.   Now to make the appropriate migrations to my lead and customer models.

Comment: However I will never need to access the states independently... also, wouldn't this end up creating a database row in the states table for every single lead?  It looks like the has_and_belongs_to_many would be better. However you did point me in the right direct.

Comment: No, the states table will not contain any leads. The leads table has a `state_id` field, which is a reference to a particular state. Multiple leads can have the same `state_id`, so there is no redundancy. And yes, you can use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association instead in this case.

Comment: I understand that you will probably never need to access the states table directly. However, it is necessary to make the whole setup work the way you need it.